# Passing aws credentials to Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, amazon-iam

I have a docker container golang code which interacts with aws resources. In the testing environment, we use iam role. But How do I test locally. How to use aws credentials to run my docker locally.I am using docker file to build the docker image.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just mount your credential directory as read-only using:

```
docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro  ...
```

given you have `root` as the user in the container and also have setup the host using this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html) for credentials file.

or pass them directly using environment variables as:

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<ACCESS_KEY> -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<SECRET_KEY> ...
```

Comment: `${USERPROFILE}` or `$env:USERPROFILE` for those using windows as a host. Is there any way to do this using a dockerfile (not docker-compose file)